# html passing parameters onclick event

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new in js/php and need help for a question about passing parameters to js function from a onclic event in a tr tag

```
echo "<tr onclick='DoNav({$row['id']})'>";
```

this code runs ok, but i need pass a second parameter: **$row['name']** but my function DoNav() seems not receive it. Thanks.

Comment: did you tried `echo "<tr onclick='DoNav({$row['id']},{$row['name']})'>";`

Comment: Can you show your `DoNav()` function as well, or at least the signature

Comment: Niranjan, yes, I tried your sintax.

Comment: `function DoNav(idUsuario){
   document.body.innerHTML +=
 '<form id="dynForm" action="admin.php" method="POST">'+
 '<input type="hidden" name="idUser" value=' + idUsuario +'>'+
 '</form>';
 document.getElementById("dynForm").submit();  }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<tr onclick="DoNav(' . $row['id'] . ')">';
```

Comment: A good answer with explanation becomes a perfect answer... and useful for others. Would you mind explaining what your solution is about?

Comment: `echo '<tr  onclick="DoNav(', $row['id'], ",'", $row["name"], "'", ')">';` was the solution.

Comment: Did you were ready to upvote my post or something else? What explanation have you expected? I didn't get any feedback from the author of the question. If it doesn't work - I'll suggest another solution. But if it's working well - it's as simple as the Rule of Three (without ambitious explanation)

Comment: actually, it's not a great idea at all to use onclick attribute in html markup. I would rather use data attributes and then from within addEventListener handler get those attributes value for each table row

Comment: For now, your sugestion is very dificult for me, I'm a beginer in html-js-php and need more time to apply. Thans

Comment: @M.Nicolau, consider this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575561/passing-php-variable-to-onclick-method.
Especially those case where data-filmid is mentioned